# Accessing private fields in an intercepted class, using ByteBuddy

Tags: java, byte-buddy

If I have a class, say:

```
public class Foo {
    private String name;

    //...

    public void someMethod(Object someArg) {
    }
}
```

.. and I would like to intercept 'someMethod', using a Java Agent, so I do something along the lines of:

```
public static void premain(String args, Instrumentation inst) {

    new AgentBuilder.Default()
            .type(ElementMatchers.named("Foo"))
            .transform((builder, typeDescription, classLoader, module)
             -> builder.method(
                 ElementMatchers.named("someMethod"))
                 .intercept(MethodDelegation.to(Interceptor.class))
            )

            .installOn(inst);
}

public class Interceptor() {
    public static void intercept(
        @AllArguments Object[] args,
        @This Foo foo,
        @SuperCall Callable zuper) {

            if (foo.name.equals("BAR") //foo.name inaccessible here
               zuper();
            else {/*something else*/}
    }
}
```

How can I use ByteBuddy to give me a way to access the 'name' field of class Foo, whilst inside my intercept method?

Can ByteBuddy expose that private variable for me to inspect (or modify I guess, but for my use-case, read-only is fine)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `@FieldValue` annotation if you only want to read a value:

```
public class Interceptor() {
  public static void intercept(
    @AllArguments Object[] args,
    @FieldValue("name") String name,
    @SuperCall Callable zuper) {
        if (name.equals("BAR"))
           zuper();
        else {/*something else*/}
  }
}
```

If you want to write a value, you have to use (and install) `@FieldAccessor`.

Comment: Ah right. Got it. That works perfectly for me as I only need read-access. Thanks.